# Regarding the immutability of pandas dataframe indexes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, immutability

I read in the documentation that the index objects are immutable and can not be changed once created. But I can change the values after creation.

Am I missing something here?

This is what I tried:

```
ser = pd.Series([5,0,3,8,4], index=['red','blue','yellow','white','green'])
ser

red       5
blue      0
yellow    3
white     8
green     4
dtype: int64

ser.index = ['red','blue','yellow','white','test']
ser

red       5
blue      0
yellow    3
white     8
test      4
dtype: int64
```

Comment: It means you can't do `ser.index[0] = 'wack'`

Comment: Semantically that's slightly different, what you're doing is replacing the index with an entirely new index, but you can't change an individual index element as @JohnGalt and the answer has shown

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Note that the culprit is in the [`__setitem__`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/indexes/base.py#L1680) method of the `Index` class:

```
def __setitem__(self, key, value):
    raise TypeError("Index does not support mutable operations")
```

This `TypeError` is raised when you try to set an element of the index. However, this says nothing about reassigning the index.

OTOH, if you consider [*`df.set_index`*](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/frame.py#L2894) which is a method to set the index, you'll see that, at the end, this is done:

```
frame.index = index  # Line 3016
```

Meaning, you may re-assign the index at any time.

---

A similar example should help. Assuming, you're aware of the immutability of strings.

```
string = 'test'
```

*This* is possible:

```
string = 'test2'  # reassignment
```

But *this* is not:

```
string[0] = c     # item assignment... mutating the same object! 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-233-27903bb729b1> in <module>()
----> 1 s[0] = c

TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment
```

---

In a similar fashion mutability != reassignment. `ser.index` works similar to this. You may think of the `index` as an ordered frozenset.

Answer (score 4):

You can *change* the object `ser.index` references like you've done, but you can't *mutate* the object once assigned:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> ser = pd.Series([5,0,3,8,4], index=['red','blue','yellow','white','green'])
>>> ser.index[2] = 'coconut'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/indexes/base.py", line 1404, in __setitem__
    raise TypeError("Index does not support mutable operations")
TypeError: Index does not support mutable operations
```

---

```
>>> lst = [''] * 5
>>> ser.index = lst
>>> ser.index
Index(['', '', '', '', ''], dtype='object')
>>> lst[:] = ['Mango', 'Banana', 'Orange', 'Pear', 'Apple'] # update list
>>> lst
['Mango', 'Banana', 'Orange', 'Pear', 'Apple']
>>> ser.index
Index(['', '', '', '', ''], dtype='object')
```