# Shape of passed values is (6, 4), indices imply (4, 4)

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to make a Pandasandas DataFrame the data is zeros with shape (6,4) and the columns are

```
col=['Example', 'Example', 'Example', 'Example']
```

and the index is a list of lists:

```
ind=[[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4]]
```

and I'm doing it in this way:

```
pd.DataFrame(np.zeros((6,4)), columns = col, index=ind )
```

but it returns an error

```
Shape of passed values is (6, 4), indices imply (4, 1)
```

I tried to replace the list with a tuple and it worked! I'm wandering why this error is happening and how to solve it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to pass an immutable object as index so that the index considers 6 indexes. You can do that by converting each of the sublists as tuples `[tuple(i) for i in ind]` -

```
ind=[[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4]]
col=['Example', 'Example', 'Example', 'Example']
pd.DataFrame(np.zeros((6,4)), columns = col, index=[tuple(i) for i in ind])
```

```
              Example  Example  Example  Example
(1, 2, 3, 4)      0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0
(1, 2, 3, 4)      0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0
(1, 2, 3, 4)      0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0
(1, 2, 3, 4)      0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0
(1, 2, 3, 4)      0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0
(1, 2, 3, 4)      0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0
```

---

You could create a multi-index out of this so that the index has 4 levels.

```
ind=[[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4]]
col=['Example', 'Example', 'Example', 'Example']
print(pd.DataFrame(np.zeros((6,4)), columns = col, index=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(ind)))
```

```
         Example  Example  Example  Example
1 2 3 4      0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0
      4      0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0
      4      0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0
      4      0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0
      4      0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0
      4      0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0

#Here first level is all 1 and second level is all 2 (and so on...)
```

Comment: is there any way to make the index as a list not a tuple

Comment: Nope , you can use multi-index however

Comment: The index has to be an immutable object and list is a mutable object.

Comment: Glad to help, do mark the answer if it helped you as it encourages me to assist you in the future as well :)

Comment: I will for sure

Comment: For more reading check this SO post as well. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46193728/regarding-the-immutability-of-pandas-dataframe-indexes